# ajax extension tabs do not show the GUI after publishing on the server 2008

Tags: asp.net

On the localhost, ajax extension tabs display correctly. however, after publishing on the server, the tabs only show the text but not the GUI.

Is there any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is because the .NET framework 4.0 targeted for the site on the server is not compatible with Ajax extension 2.0